# Does WCSessionDelegate get an initial sessionReachabilityDidChange after activating WCSession?

Tags: watchos-2, watchconnectivity

When setting up a WCSession in a watchOS app, does the WCSessionDelegate's `sessionReachabilityDidChange:` method always get invoked immediately after calling `activateSession`? From my testing this seems to be true but I am not finding any confirmation of this in documentation.

I ask because if I can rely on `sessionReachabilityDidChange:` being called immediately after activating the session, I can remove some redundant code from applicationDidBecomeActive that checks for a reachable session and sends some initial messages to the iPhone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just call it yourself after you are done doing all your set up? That way you don't rely on any undocumented behavior, yet you don't have to duplicate code in two places

Comment: I could. My question is whether this is necessary at all though.

Comment: I do not believe it is documented anywhere, which means relying on it could break you in the future